# Where to check log file for JVM exception?

Tags: jvm, jmeter

I receive this message after executing a load test in Jmeter

Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. See log file for details.

Where can I see the log file?

Answer (score 1):

In case of JVM shutdown this way the log should be in JMeter's "bin" folder under the name like `hs_err_pidXXXXXX.log`

The error indicates that the operating system is not able to create a new thread (perhaps you reached some form of limit) so refer your OS documentation to learn how to increase it.

- Windows: most likely you are not getting this error on Windows as it has [quite high limits](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/)
- Linux: [How to set or change the default soft or hard limit for the number of user's processes?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/406663)
- MacOSX: temporary - the same as for Linux, permanent - [different depending on MacOSX version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persist-ulimit-settings-in-osx-mavericks)

Just in case double check you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article